# How can I recorgnise a mouseclick in a JPanel only a specified area?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I try to create a class that could added another JComponnent an create a clickable Settings-Icon in the Top-Right Corner.

I like to add some kind of ActionListener, that raises when the user click on the area of the `g.drawImage(image, getWidth() - widgetSize, 0, widgetSize, widgetSize, imageObserver)`.

Is this the right way to solve this problem? Or are there better ways for that?

```
package de.display;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JWidget extends JPanel {

    private int widgetSize = 50;
    private boolean showWidgetIcon = true;

    Image image;
    ImageObserver imageObserver;

    public JWidget() {
        this(new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Icon-Settings.png"));
    }

    public JWidget(String filename) {
        super();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);
        image = icon.getImage();
        imageObserver = icon.getImageObserver();
    }

    public JWidget(ImageIcon icon){
        super();
        image = icon.getImage();
        imageObserver = icon.getImageObserver();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(showWidgetIcon)
        {
            g.drawImage(image, getWidth() - widgetSize, 0, widgetSize, widgetSize, imageObserver);
        }
    }

    public int getWidgetSize() {
        return widgetSize;
    }

    public void setWidgetSize(int widgetSize) {
        this.widgetSize = widgetSize;
    }

    public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon icon) {
        image = icon.getImage();
        imageObserver = icon.getImageObserver();
    }

    public boolean isWidgetIconVisible() {
        return showWidgetIcon;
    }

    public void setShowWidgetVisibility(boolean showWidgetIcon) {
        this.showWidgetIcon = showWidgetIcon;
    }

    public void addPressSettingsActionListener(ActionListener actionListener)
    {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, actionListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `MouseListener`. The [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) contains all necessary details.

Comment: `new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Icon-Settings.png")` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to add a button with the given icon and no text (IMHO), which is placed at the given area of the panel. You can also set the border of the button to null (or EmptyBorder) if you only want to have the icon painted. For some L&F you also need to call the method `AbstractButton.setContentAreaFilled(boolean)` with parameter false.
Method `addActionListener` can forward the call to the corresponded method of the enclosed button.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

public class JWidget extends JPanel {

    private boolean showWidgetIcon = true;

    private BasicButton button = new BasicButton(null, 50);

    public JWidget() {
        this(new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Icon-Settings.png"));
    }

    public JWidget(String filename) {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);
        button.setIcon(icon);
        initLayout();
    }

    public JWidget(ImageIcon icon) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        button.setIcon(icon);
        initLayout();
    }

    private void initLayout() {
        removeAll();
        if (showWidgetIcon) {
            JPanel rightLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
            add(rightLayoutPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            rightLayoutPanel.add(button);
        }
    }

    public int getWidgetSize() {
        return button.getButtonSize();
    }

    public void setWidgetSize(int widgetSize) {
        button.setButtonSize(widgetSize);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon icon) {
        button.setIcon(icon);
    }

    public boolean isWidgetIconVisible() {
        return showWidgetIcon;
    }

    public void setShowWidgetVisibility(boolean showWidgetIcon) {
        this.showWidgetIcon = showWidgetIcon;
        initLayout();
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        button.addActionListener(al);
    }

    private static class BasicButton extends JButton {
        private int buttonSize;

        /**
         * 
         */
        public BasicButton(Icon anIcon, int aSize) {
            super(anIcon);
            buttonSize = aSize;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            setUI(new BasicButtonUI());
            setBorder(null);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(buttonSize, buttonSize);
        }

        public int getButtonSize() {
            return buttonSize;
        }

        public void setButtonSize(int size) {
            this.buttonSize = size;
        }
    }
}
```